# Rust: Make unwrap() print error.display() instead of error.debug()

Tags: debugging, rust, error-handling, display, unwrap

In a Rust program, I am using a `Result` which uses a `String` as its `Error` type:

`fn foo() -> Result<String, String>`

The String I return as an error looks something like this:
`lorem\nipsum`

Now I call my function and unwrap it as such:
`foo.unwrap();`

Now when `foo()` returns an `Error`, it prints the error as follows:
`lorem\nipsum`

However, what I actually would want to see is the following error message:

```
lorem
ipsum
```

As far as I can tell, the reason for this behaviour is that `unwrap()`, calls `debug()` instead of `display()` which in the case of the String, is implemented differently (a new line is displayed as a new line, but debug-printed as "\n").

Is there a quick way how I could unwrap() my result in a way that it calls `display()` instead of `debug()` for the printed error to actually show newlines instead of "\n"s?

Comment: The existing answer explains why you should probably not try to do this, but also: it is impossible to change how `unwrap` writes out its error, as it is hard-coded to use the `Debug` formatting: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/result.rs.html#1779-1786

Comment: If you return the error rather than unwrapping it, so that eventually it's returned from `main` or from a test function, then that will typically end up with the error `Display` (rather than `Debug`) form being printed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`unwrap` is not supposed to display pretty error messages. When `unwrap` panics, something is supposed to have gone horribly wrong. If you want to print out the `String` inside an `Err` you can print it to `stderr` with `eprintln!` and then handle the error properly after that:

```
if let Err(e) = foo() {
    eprintln!("{}", e);
    // handle the error properly here
}
```

Comment: IOW: a failed `unwrap()` is a bug in the program.